# jolt concatenate array elements to single object

Tags: json, jolt

I started with Jolt, but I can't concatenate the elements of the array to single string,

I have json like this:

```
{
  "partNb": "1234",
  "partDescriptions": [
    {
      "country": "GB",
      "language": "en",
      "content": "1 tool description in en_GB"
    },
    {
      "country": "GB",
      "language": "en",
      "content": "2 tool description in en_GB"
    }
  ]
}
```

and  with jolt spec:

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "partNb": "id",
      "partDescriptions": {
        "*": {
          "content": "description"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

For this I  have this output:

```
{
  "id" : "1234",
  "description" : [ "1 tool description in en_GB", "2 tool description in en_GB" ]
}
```

but how to get result like this?:

```
{
  "id" : "1234",
  "description" :  "1 tool description in en_GB , 2 tool description in en_GB" 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Spec

```
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "description": "=join(', ',@(1,description))"
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer, but the result is :
 "description" : "{country=GB, language=en, content=1 tool description in en_GB}, {country=GB, language=en, content=2 tool description in en_GB}"

Answer (score 2):

To get only content fields concatenated into descriptions:

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "partDescriptions": {
        "*": {
          "content": {
            "@": "content"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "description": "=join(', ', @(2,content))"
    }
  }
]
```

Output:

```
{
  "content" : [ "1 tool description in en_GB", "2 tool description in en_GB" ],
  "description" : "1 tool description in en_GB, 2 tool description in en_GB"
}
```